# Fan speed and control

Tags: 16.04, fan, temperature, fancontrol

I have small problem with motherboard sensors.
Motherboard has 3 fan connectors.
In BIOS I have menu with hardware health.
There is sensors for CPU temperature, Fan RPM and some other temperatures.
Also BIOS allows to control CPU and Front Fan.
But BIOS controls only fan speed depended from Processor temperature.
Lm-sensors packge is installed and see only temperatures:

```
unim95@host:~$ sensors
acpitz-virtual-0
Adapter: Virtual device << I don't what is it(maybe Intel Graphics)
temp1:        +45.0°C  (crit = +120.0°C)

radeon-pci-0100
Adapter: PCI adapter << Radeon R7 250X
temp1:        +34.0°C  (crit = +120.0°C, hyst = +90.0°C)

coretemp-isa-0000
Adapter: ISA adapter << Processor Core i5-460M
Core 0:       +45.0°C  (high = +95.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
Core 2:       +46.0°C  (high = +95.0°C, crit = +105.0°C)
```

- OS: Ubuntu 16.04 + Mate desktop
- M/B: Jetway [NF98-QH57](http://www.jetwaycomputer.com/NF98.html) (QM 57 chipset)
- Processor: Core i5-460M

How can I find my Fan RPM and control it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately the QM57 chipset does not support reading or controlling the fan RPM. See page 79 of the datasheet [here](http://www.intel.com/content/dam/www/public/us/en/documents/datasheets/5-chipset-3400-chipset-datasheet.pdf)

Comment: Wow. Nice documentation.  Do you given false page? Schould it be page 79 and not 69?